# Read a full page with aspx form Load dynamic in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, load

I need to read this page in **WCF service**
http://bvmf.bmfbovespa.com.br/cias-listadas/empresas-listadas/ResumoEmpresaPrincipal.aspx?codigoCvm=9512&idioma=pt-br

But I want to read this node generate dynamic by server class="ficha responsive"
When I use a method like

```
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://bvmf.bmfbovespa.com.br/cias-listadas/empresas-listadas/ResumoEmpresaPrincipal.aspx?codigoCvm=9512&idioma=pt-br")
```

I not get full page because page call dynamic this form

```
form name="aspnetForm" 
method="post" 
action="ResumoEmpresaPrincipal.aspx?codigoCvm=9512&amp;idioma+=+pt+-+br&amp;idioma=pt-br" 
id="aspnetForm"
```

How I can get load FULL page or post data to this webform in C#?? or load a full HTML Content ?

```
ResumoEmpresaPrincipal.aspx?codigoCvm=9512
```

Comment: Please clarify how existing solutions for crawling dynamic pages do not work for you. In the current state post show no research (which you've probably done already) and hence likely will collect downvotes for "this post does not show any research" reason.

Comment: My Friend I forget cite a important note, I need do it in WCF service, and with webbrowser component I get a Error when execute load page, because I don't have a main thread. Do you some sugestion to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to read a full page content are  in this post

[Scraping webpage generated by javascript with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288726/scraping-webpage-generated-by-javascript-with-c-sharp)