# Webclient not returning any data

Tags: c#, webclient, web-client

I'm using below given code to download content of a webpage.

```
 using (var w = new System.Net.WebClient())
                {

                    w.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                    w.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla / 5.0(Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit / 537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome / 59.0.3071.104 Safari / 537.36";
                    var HtmlMarkup = w.DownloadString("http://www.as.com/statistics/announcements.do?by=asxCode&asxCode=HLO&timeframe=Y&year=" + i);
}
```

The response i'm getting doesn't have any content. But when I browse the page the data load as normal.

The return string of the call is

```
    <html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1"/>
<meta http-equiv="CacheControl" content="no-cache"/>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the page content.</noscript>

<APM_DO_NOT_TOUCH>
<script language="javascript">

(function(){
    var securemsg;
    var packmsg;
    var CryptoUtils;

try{(function(){try{var IS,lS,oS=1;for(var OS=0;OS<lS;++OS)oS+=3;IS=oS;window._===IS&&(window._=++IS)}catch(ZS){window._=IS}var __=window.sdkljshr489=!0;function i_(S){window.sdkljshr489&&S&&(__=!1);return __}function I_(){}i_(window[I_.name]===I_);i_("undefined"===window.vodsS0);window.vodsS0=null;i_(/\x3c/.test(function(){return"\x3c"})&/x3d/.test(function(){return"0";"x3d"}));var j_=/mobi/i.test(navigator.userAgent),L_=+new Date,o_=j_?3E4:3E3;
function O_(){return i_(L_+o_<(L_=+new Date))}(function(){var S={decrypt:function(S){try{return JSON.parse(function(S){S=S.split("l");var l="";for(var L=0;L<S.length;++L)l+=String.fromCharCode(S[L]);return l}(S))}catch(L){}}};return S={configuration:S.decrypt("123l34l97l99l116l105l118l101l34l58l34l110l111l34l44l34l100l101l98l117l103l103l105l110l103l34l58l34l110l111l34l44l34l109l111l100l117l108l101l49l34l58l34l101l110l97l98l108l101l100l34l44l34l109l111l100l117l108l101l50l34l58l34l101l110l97l98l108l101l100l34l44l34l109l111l100l117l108l101l51l34l58l34l101l110l97l98l108l101l100l34l44l34l109l111l100l117l108l101l52l34l58l34l101l110l97l98l108l101l100l34l125")}})();
window.oi={iI:"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"};function I(S){return 231>S}function J(){var S=arguments.length,l=[];for(var L=0;L<S;++L)l.push(arguments[L]-64);return String.fromCharCode.apply(String,l)}function z(S){return S.toString(36)}(function z_(l){l&&"number"!==typeof l||("number"!==typeof l&&(l=1E3),l=Math.max(l,1),setInterval(function(){z_(l-10)},l))})(O_());var n;})();}finally{sdkljshr489=false;ie9rgb4=void(0);};
eval((ie9rgb4=function (){var m='function () {/*fQb f_TcC}-di`U_V YU)bWR$+dbikuVe^SdY_^uvkdbikfQb 9Cy\\Cy_C-!yJO-!ycO-!yCY-!yOY-!yYY-!y9Y-!yZY-!+V_bufQb ?C-}+?C,\\C+xx?Cv_Cx-"yJOx-"ycOx-"yCYx-"yOYx-"yYYx-"y9Yx-"yZYx-#+9C-_CxJOxcOxCYxOYxYYx9YxZY+gY^T_g{O---9CssugY^T_g{O-xx9CvmSQdSXuJCvkgY^T_g{O-9CmfQb OO-gY^T_g{cT[\\ZcXb$()-n}+Ve^SdY_^ YOuCvkgY^T_g{cT[\\ZcXb$()ssCssuOO-n!v+bUdeb^ OOmVe^SdY_^ 9OuvkmYOugY^T_gK9O{^Q]UM---9Ov+YOuoe^TUVY^UTo---gY^T_g{f_TcC}v+gY^T_g{f_TcC}-^e\\\\+YOu|Lh#S|{dUcduVe^SdY_^uvkbUdeb^oLh#Somvs|h#T|{dUcduVe^SdY_^uvkbUdeb^o}o+oh#Tomvv+\r\nfQb ZO-|]_RY|Y{dUcdu^QfYWQd_b{ecUb1WU^dvy<O-x^Ug 4QdUy_O-ZO/#5$*#5#+Ve^SdY_^ ?OuvkbUdeb^ YOu<Ox_O,u<O-x^Ug 4QdUvvm\r\nuVe^SdY_^ \\YuvkfQb \\-n!+Ve^SdY_^ <u\\vkV_bufQb <-}+\\zz+v<x-?uT_Se]U^d{T_Se]U^d5\\U]U^dy^e\\\\v+bUdeb^ <mVe^SdY_^ ?u\\y<vkfQb c-ofYo+<-<ll^Ug J+bUdeb^ OCu\\yVe^SdY_^u\\vk\\{cUd1ddbYRedUuoTQdQzoxcy<{<Cuvv+bUdeb^ ?u\\y<vmy^e\\\\vmVe^SdY_^ JuvkdXYc{c-!+dXYc{J-}+dXYc{9-dXYc{c+dXYc{\\-^e\\\\+dXYc{<C-Ve^SdY_^uvkdXYc{\\-dXYc{JxdXYc{9+YVunYc6Y^YdUudXYc{\\vvbUdeb^ dXYc{bUcUduvydXYc{<Cuv+dXYc{J-dXYc{9+dXYc{9-dXYc{\\+dXYc{\\-^e\\\\+bUdeb^ dXYc{9m+dXYc{bUcUd-Ve^SdY_^uvkdXYc{cxx+dXYc{J-}+dXYc{9-dXYc{cmmfQb c-n!+Ve^SdY_^ CCu\\y<vkfQb ?-\r\nT_Se]U^d{SbUQdU5\\U]U^du\\v+<-<llT_Se]U^d{R_Ti+<{Q``U^T3XY\\Tu?v+?ss?{cdi\\Ussu?{cdi\\U{TYc`\\Qi-o^_^UovmVe^SdY_^ YCu<y?vk?-?ll<+fQb J-olo+Ve^SdY_^ CCu\\vk\\-\\{c`\\YduJv+fQb <-KM+V_bufQb ?-}+?,\\{\\U^WdX+xx?vkfQb c-ooy<C-\\K?M{c`\\Yduoyov+V_bufQb ZC-}+ZC,<C{\\U^WdX+xxZCvcx-<CKZCMKZCM+<{`ecXucvmbUdeb^ <mfQb OC-}y:C-oTQdQ\\YcdyTUdQY\\cyU]RUTyVYWebUyXbY]Wycdb_^WyQbdYS\\UyV_b]QTTbUcclQeTY_yR\\_S[ae_dUyQbUQyc_ebSUyY^`edlSQ^fQcyV_b]y\\Y^[ydRQcUy_`dY_^yTUdQY\\cyQbdYS\\Uo+:C{c`\\YduJv+:C-CCu:Cv+:C-^Ug BUW5h`u:C{Z_Y^uJvyoWov+gXY\\Uu:C{UhUSu<vv:C-\r\n^Ug BUW5h`uuoox^Ug 4QdUvK(MyoWovy\\ssuc-OOvyxxOC+bUdeb^ ?uOCss!vmVe^SdY_^ OCu\\y<y?vku?-?llcvssCCuoTYfoy\\v+\\-\\{SXY\\TbU^+fQb J-}+V_bufQb OC Y^ \\vk?-\\KOCM+dbik? Y^cdQ^SU_V 8D=<5\\U]U^dssu<u?vyxxJvmSQdSXu:CvkmmbUdeb^ JmYCu\\Yy<vmvuv+\r\ncUSebU]cW-kcZC*Ve^SdY_^uCvkbUdeb^ cUSebU]cWKju"(()\'vMucUSebU]cW{jYuu9u"%&vy}vyCy9u&}%v/}*!vyVe^SdY_^uvkbUdeb^ CdbY^WK:u!&&y!\'(y!\'%y!\'#y!#!y!&(y!&!y!\'(y!#!y!\'%y!&$y!&%vMu=QdXKju"&"}&}!!vMu=QdXKju!&%}$\'#\'#$vMuvwu9u!(#v/"%&*#!#vxu9u!$"v/!*}vvru9u!#%v/"%&*")"vvmvKju)!("#)vMuoovmyjC*Ve^SdY_^uCvkbUdeb^uuCsu9u()#v/"$!*"%%vv,,u9u")\'v/"!*"$vluCsu9u"\'$v/\'$&%$*&%"(}vv,,u9u)\')vy(vlC..u9u%%#v/!}*(vsu9u%)}v/\'}"!"*&%"(}vlC..u9u$("v/!)*"$vsu9u#\'v/"%%*"&(vv...u9u)})vy}vmy9}*Ve^SdY_^uCy\\vkV_bufQb <-ooy?-u9u\'(\'vy}v+?,\r\nCKju!")$#))"}%vM+?xxv<x-CdbY^WKoLe}}&&b_]3Lh&(Qb3_TUoMuCK:u!&#y!&(y!&!y!\'(y!#!y!\'%y!&$y!&%y!")y!(}vMuu?xCKju!")$#))"}%vMz\\vrCKju!")$#))"}%vMvv+bUdeb^ <myYZC*Ve^SdY_^uCy\\vkbUdeb^ cUSebU]cW{9}uCyCKju!")$#))"}%vMz\\vmy<O*Ve^SdY_^uCy\\vkYVuCKju!")$#))"}%vMn-\\Kju!")$#))"}%vMvdXb_g cUSebU]cW{ZCuCvycUSebU]cW{ZCu\\vyoo+V_bufQb <-ooy?-u9u"#$vy}v+?,CKju!")$#))"}%vM+?xxv<x-CdbY^WKoLe}}&&b_]3Lh&(Qb3_TUoMuCK:u!&#y!&(y!&!y!\'(y!#!y!\'%y!&$y!&%y!")y!(}vMu?vN\r\n\\KoLe}}&#XQbLh$#_TU1doMu?vv+bUdeb^ <my\\C*Ve^SdY_^uCy\\vkbUdeb^uuC...u9u%"\'vy}vvxu\\...u9u$#%vy}vvsu9u!"#v/$")$)&\'")%*"!$\'$(#&$\'vv...u9u$\'!vy}vmyO:*Ve^SdY_^uCy\\vkbUdeb^uuC...u9u(!%vy}vvz\\su9u$!"v/"!$\'$(#&$\'*$")$)&\'")%vv...u9u%#)vy}vmy_%*Ve^SdY_^uCy\\y<vkdbikYVuCKju!")$#))"}%vMn-u9u!(!v/!&*""vvdXb_goo+YVu\\Kju!")$#))"}%vMn-u9u#!v/(*\'vvdXb_goo+fQb ?-cUSebU]cW{c_uCv+?K9u)}}vy}M-cUSebU]cW{jCu?K9u!!}vy}Mv+?K9u%""v/}*!M-cUSebU]cW{jCu?K9u&!$v/}*!Mv+?K9u#%)vy"M-cUSebU]cW{jCu?K9u!(%v/\r\n"*!Mv+?K9u#%)v/"*#M-cUSebU]cW{jCu?K9u&"!v/"*#Mv+fQb J-cUSebU]cW{c_u\\vyc-cUSebU]cW{jCuJK9u"$vy}MvyCC-cUSebU]cW{jCuJK9u$#"v/}*!MvyYC-u</9u#&)v/"!$\'$(#&$\'*$"$\'})\'"#}$*u9u)$%vy}vv...u9u(&vy}v+YVu<vV_bufQb OC-9u\'")v/!#*!%+OC.-u9u($)vy}v+OCzzvfQb ZC-cUSebU]cW{\\Cuc,,u9u\'$%v/%*$vNc...u9u%(}vy%vycvy<C-cUSebU]cW{\\CuYCy?KYC...u9u!$&vy!!vsu9u&\'\'v/!*#vMvyCC-cUSebU]cW{O:uCCyZCN<CvyYC-cUSebU]cW{O:uYCy9u#}}v/"!$\'$(#&$\'*"&%$$#%\'&)vyCO-cUSebU]cW{\\CuCC,,u9u$\'%v/%*$vNCC...u9u!(\'v/%*&vyCCvycC-cUSebU]cW{\\CuYCy?KYCsu9u&!\'v/\r\n"*#vMvyc-cUSebU]cW{O:ucyCONcCv+U\\cU V_buYC-u9u)!}vy}vyOC-u9u#(%vy}v+OC,u9u#%\'v/"!*!&v+OCxxvZC-cUSebU]cW{\\CuCC,,u9u#"#v/"*$vNCC...u9u)!\'vy%vyCCvy<C-cUSebU]cW{\\CuYCy?KYCsu9u\'%"v/!*#vMvyc-cUSebU]cW{\\CucyZCN<CvyYC-cUSebU]cW{\\CuYCy9u\'}}v/"!$\'$(#&$\'*"&%$$#%\'&)vyCO-cUSebU]cW{\\Cuc,,u9u%\'}v/%*$vNc...u9u!!)v/%*$vycvycC-cUSebU]cW{\\CuYCy?KYC...u9u\')v/!!*!#vsu9u$#!vy#vMvyCC-cUSebU]cW{\\CuCCyCONcCv+c-cUSebU]cW{jCucv+CC-cUSebU]cW{jCuCCv+bUdeb^ cUSebU]cW{j"uKcyCCMvmSQdSXu\\OvkdXb_g \\O+mmy\\Z*Ve^SdY_^uCy\\y<vkbUdeb^ cUSebU]cW{_%uCy\r\n\\y<vmy?Z*Ve^SdY_^uCy\\vkV_bufQb <-ooy?-u9u!&"vy}v+?,\\+?xxv<x-C+bUdeb^ <my?_*Ve^SdY_^uCy\\y<vk\\-\\zCKju!")$#))"}%vMr\\zu9u)%!v/}*!v+V_bufQb ?-ooyJ-u9u!\'vy}v+J,\\+Jxxv?x-<+bUdeb^ Cx?xCdbY^WK:u!&&y!\'(y!\'%y!\'#y!#!y!&(y!&!y!\'(y!#!y!\'%y!&$y!&%vMu\\vmyJ"*Ve^SdY_^uCvkbUdeb^ CKju$(}#"\')(vMuu9u"\'"vy}vyCKju!")$#))"}%vMzCKoLe}}&#XQbLh$#_TU1doMuCKju!")$#))"}%vMzu9u%$\'v/}*!vvzu9u$!v/!*}vvmyZ_*Ve^SdY_^uCy\\y<vkfQb ?-:u&$y&$y&$y&$y&$y&$y&$y&$vyJ-oo+YVu<vkYVu\\Kju!")$#))"}%vMru9u%}}v/!}*(vn-\r\nu9u#(&vy}vvdXb_goo+<-\\Kju!")$#))"}%vM|u9u$}(v/&*(v+V_bufQb c-u9u&#\'vy}v+c,<+cxxvfQb CC-\\Kju!\'$#))!)(#vMucwu9u#$)v/)*(vyu9u%""vy(vvyJ-JxcUSebU]cW{<OucUSebU]cW{\\ZuCyCCy?Ouvvy?vy?-CC+bUdeb^ cUSebU]cW{J"uJvm\\-cUSebU]cW{?_u\\y9u\'\'v/(*&yoLe}}VVov+<-\\Kju!")$#))"}%vM|u9u"$v/(*&v+V_buc-u9u"}"vy}v+c,<+cxxvCC-\\Kju!\'$#))!)(#vMucwu9u\')$v/)*(vyu9u)\'"vy(vvy?-cUSebU]cW{\\ZuCycUSebU]cW{<Ou?yCCvyn!vyJx-?+bUdeb^ Jmy<Z*Ve^SdY_^uCvkfQb \\-ju"}!"$(\'"(")(&v+C-cUSebU]cW{?_uCy9u#"!v/$*(yju#$vv+V_bufQb <-CKju!")$#))"}%vM|\r\nu9u)}v/(*)vy?-u9u&%$vy}v+?,<+?xxvfQb J-CKju!\'$#))!)(#vMu?wu9u$$#vy(vy9u!%}v/(*\'vyJ-JxcUSebU]cW{<OuJy:u"$\'y"(!y)&y\'\'y!"%y"&"y!\'"y!#\'vvy\\-cUSebU]cW{<Ou\\ycUSebU]cW{\\ZuJy\\yn!vv+bUdeb^ \\myY_*Ve^SdY_^uCy\\vkfQb <-CKju!")$#))"}%vM,-u9u((\'v/!$*!&v/C*cUSebU]cW{<ZuCv+<Kju!")$#))"}%vM,u9u)"%v/"}*!&vssu<x-cUSebU]cW{?ZuoLh}}oyu9u\'$&v/)*!&vz<Kju!")$#))"}%vMvv+fQb ?-cUSebU]cW{<Ou<ycUSebU]cW{?Zu:u!%&vy9u\'(!v/!)*!&vvy<-cUSebU]cW{<Ou<ycUSebU]cW{?Zuju&vy9u)}!v/!%*!&vv+bUdeb^ cUSebU]cW{<Zu?xcUSebU]cW{<Zu<x\\vvmy?OC*9u!(#v/\r\n(*$yZC*Ve^SdY_^uCvkbUdeb^ cUSebU]cWKju"(()\'vMucUSebU]cW{jYuu9u$}$vy}vyCKju!")$#))"}%vMy9u\')!v/}*!vyVe^SdY_^u\\vk\\->e]RUbuCKoLh&#Le}}&(Lh&!Le}}\'"Lh$#Le}}&VLh&$Le}}&%Lh$!Le}}\'$oMu\\vvK:u!(}y!\'%y!$\'y!(}y!\'(y!&)y!\'$y!&\'vMu9u$#)v/!)*!&v+bUdeb^ \\Kju!")$#))"}%vM--u9u\'("v/}*!v/oLh#}ox\\*\\mvKju)!("#)vMuoovmy_Z*Ve^SdY_^uCvkbUdeb^ cUSebU]cWKju"(()\'vMucUSebU]cW{jYuu9u&(%vy\r\n}vyCKju!")$#))"}%vMyu9u\'\'}vy"vvyVe^SdY_^u\\vkbUdeb^ CdbY^WK:u!&&y!\'(y!\'%y!\'#y!#!y!&(y!&!y!\'(y!#!y!\'%y!&$y!&%vMu>e]RUbuoLe}}#}Lh\'(oxCKju!\'$#))!)(#vMu\\y9u%\'&v/!*"vvvmvKju)!("#)vMuoovmyjY*Ve^SdY_^uCy\\y<vkYVu<,-u9u\'}#vy}vvdXb_goo+V_bufQb ?-KM+C,\\+Cx-<v?Kju!"}&#}%vMuCv+bUdeb^ ?myZ}*Ve^SdY_^uCy\\y<vkYVu<.-u9u"\'"vy}vvdXb_goo+V_bufQb ?-KM+C.\\+Cx-<v?Kju!"}&#}%vMuCv+bUdeb^ ?my9%*Ve^SdY_^uCvkbUdeb^ Csu9u"!%v/"%%*"!#vmy<"*Ve^SdY_^uCvkYVuCKju!")$#))"}%vM.u9u)"&v/"*$vvdXb_goo+V_bufQb \\-\r\nu9u)%)vy}vy<-u9u#}!vy}v+<,CKju!")$#))"}%vM+<xxv\\-u\\,,u9u"%!v/&*(vvxCK:u!&#y!&(y!&!y!\'(y!#!y!\'%y!&$y!&%y!")y!(}vMu<v+bUdeb^ \\...u9u\'"vy}vmy?"*Ve^SdY_^uCy\\vkYVuC,u9u$"vy}vvdXb_goo+di`U_V \\--ju(&$&$($#\'%)})#vssu\\-9u!#v/$*"v+bUdeb^ cUSebU]cWKju"(()\'vMucUSebU]cW{Z}u\\zu9u($!v/}*!vyu9u!"$vyz!vyu9u$%vyz!vvyVe^SdY_^u\\vkbUdeb^ CdbY^WKoLe}}&&Lh\'"Le}}&VLh&TLe}}$#Lh&(Le}}&!Lh\'"Le}}$#Lh&VLe}}&$Lh&%oMucUSebU]cW{9%uC..\r\nu9u\'$v/(*)vw\\vvmvKju)!("#)vMuoovmyc_*Ve^SdY_^uCvkV_bufQb \\-KMy<-u9u!!#vy}v+<,CKju!")$#))"}%vM+<x-9u&))v/#*$v\\Kju!"}&#}%vMucUSebU]cW{<"uCKju!\'$#))!)(#vMu<yu9u"%!vy$vvvv+bUdeb^ \\myj"*Ve^SdY_^uCvkbUdeb^ cUSebU]cWKju"(()\'vMucUSebU]cW{jYuu9u\'("vy}vyCKju!")$#))"}%vMy9u$))v/}*!vyVe^SdY_^u\\vkbUdeb^ cUSebU]cW{?"uCK\\My9u!})v/$*%vmvKju)!("#)vMuoovmy?J*Ve^SdY_^uCvkV_bufQb \\-ooy<-u9u\'(vy}v+<,CKju!")$#))"}%vM+xx<v\\-
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems the actual webpage is loaded using Javascript. Try using C#'s WebBrowser to navigate the webpage then from there get the response, See Răzvan Panda's [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7359217/3862763)

Comment: I cannot use winforms as it is an MVC application

Comment: Try reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/24289395/3862763 see if it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked for me but still having an issue. I'm trying to get dynamic data using different query string. But data not refreshing.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by "data not refreshing"? is it the response data from the webpage?

Comment: I'm trying to get a website's dynamic content using different querystring. First call returning the data but consecutive call not.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, after acquiring the first set of data from the first call the second call does not changed the data from before? Also please update you question with corresponding updated code, thanks!

Comment: Now it always return error 'System.InvalidOperationException' OpenQA.Selenium.Html5.IApplicationCache {System.InvalidOperationException}

Message:

Driver does not support manipulating the HTML5 application cache. Use the HasApplicationCache property to test for the driver capability

Comment: which part exactly does it cause the error, during call etc.? please update your code above, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Many pages look for things in the headers to ensure your not scraping the page, that could be happening here.

The best way is download [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) it's free. Close all your internet browsers and run it then navigate the page in a browser and it records all the data passed. You can then pause it and examine exactly what is being sent and replicate it.

Can also use the Plugin [Request to Code](http://www.chadsowald.com/software/fiddler-extension-request-to-code) which you can use to create the C# code to match the request for you, then just paste into your code or modify as you need.

It's the easiest way I've found. Just navigate the site and click to get the source and in less than a minute you have working code.

Comment: I looked at the traffic. It is returning 200 ok. The problem seems to be with javascrt as it says to enable javascript.

Comment: Yeah you will have problems if the parts of the page you want are rendered using Javascript, because they will not be available if you just do a WebClient.DownloadString(). In this case you need an engine to render the Javascript. One way is using the Webbrowser control, so it renders the JavaScript, then you can access the HTML after the Javascript has done it's work.