# Phantomjs caching issue

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm following [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24289395/3862763) to get a website's dynamic content inside an MVC application.

I've received the data once or twice, but after that I'm getting an error -

> ApplicationCache driver.ApplicationCache threw an exception of type
>   'System.InvalidOperationException' OpenQA.Selenium.Html5.IApplicationCache {System.InvalidOperationException}
>   Message:
>   Driver does not support manipulating the HTML5 application cache. Use the HasApplicationCache property to test for the driver capability

Answer (score 0):

The error that you're encountering is due to the fact that PhantomJS can't find anything in the `appCache` and hence throws this exception. Please see the underlying code [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.cs), which states

```
public IApplicationCache ApplicationCache
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.appCache == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Driver does not support manipulating the HTML5 application cache. Use the HasApplicationCache property to test for the driver capability");
            }

            return this.appCache;
        }
    }
```

And the reason, why this is coming to be `null` is that currently PhantomJS doesn't supports this app caching. The default capabilities for this is set to `false` in the PhantomJS code . You can see this [here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/056aa50c19b31de967ec7c30e59c6cb16680e48d/src/ghostdriver/session.js), which mentions

```
 _defaultCapabilities{
      "applicationCacheEnabled" : false,
 }
```