# HttpClient sending get request to angularjs url with #fragment

Tags: c#, httpclient

I would like to know what is the proper way to send a get request to a URL with # in it, for example http://xxx/#/home in old angularjs that still has # in their route?

I am using the .net HttpClient class, and I tried

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://xxx/#/home");

and  i am getting badrequest in response until i remove the # part.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: This [seems to be what you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288726/scraping-webpage-generated-by-javascript-with-c-sharp). In `http://xxx/#/home`, a web browser will load `http://xxx/` (i.e. index.html, or similar), and then try to find the anchor `home` within the page. Web apps use the anchor (aka fragment) to target page states, but to do that outside the browser, you need to execute the javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scraping webpage generated by javascript with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288726/scraping-webpage-generated-by-javascript-with-c-sharp)